# vim colorscheme not loading in the new tab

Tags: vim, color-scheme, system-verilog

I have been working to change my vim's colorscheme and I finally felt I got it just right. I am working with systemverilog (.sv) files and usually need to have 4-5 tabs open at a time.

The first file that I open from the terminal in vim, loads the colorscheme just fine. If I open a new vim tab (`:tabnew file_name`) from this file, opening another sv file, it comes up just showing one color. I have to open a new terminal tab to get the colorscheme working in another file.

I have my .vimrc file in the home directory and also my .vim folder with the color folder inside it. I tried the following command:

```
:scriptnames
```

in both the tabs and they show the color scheme located in the customized color folder, along with the default locations.

```
  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim72/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin.vim
  7: /home/username/.vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/nosyntax.vim
  9: /home/username/.vim/plugin/matchit.vim
 10: /home/username/.vim/syntax/verilog_systemverilog.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/verilog.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim72/indent.vim
 13: /home/username/.vim/colors/koehler.vim
 14: /home/username/.vim/plugin/matchit2.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/filetype.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/gzip.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/matchparen.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/spellfile.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/tohtml.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim72/scripts.vim
```

Any workaround this issue?

Edit: I have been able to solve this issue for .sv files by adding the following to my .vimrc file:

```
Au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sv set filetype=verilog
```

But this obviously is not a generic solution for all filetypes.

Edit: Adding link to the vimrc file: [vimrc file](https://www.firedrive.com/file/B733AB9642927B2F/)

Comment: The only colorscheme in that list is `koehler.vim`, is that the one you have modified? Can you post it and show your modifications? And your `.vimrc`? Also, I don't think `nosyntax.vim` should be here.

Comment: I have added the link to the .vimrc file up there. Also, there was no significant change to the koehler.vim apart from changing a "white" to a "light blue". What would you suggest I should do with the nosyntax.vim? I certainly did not add it in the first place.

Comment: .vimrc link is down (firedrive.com is down and marked as "deceptive" by Google)

Answer (score 2):

Your `.vimrc` is a complete mess.

- The lines below are *totally* useless:

  ```
  source ~/.vim/plugin/matchit.vim
  source /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/syntax.vim
  source ~/.vim/syntax/verilog_systemverilog.vim
  ```

  They are useless because all those files are sourced automatically: after your `.vimrc` is sourced during startup for the first one; after a `Syntax` event (triggered by `syntax on`, which is already elsewhere in your `.vimrc`) for the second; after a file was recognized as `verilog` for the third.
- Same for these ones:

  ```
  " Set up the connection between FileType and Syntax autocommands.
  " This makes the syntax automatically set when the file type is detected.
  augroup syntax
  au! FileType *      exe "set syntax=" . expand("<amatch>")
  augroup END
  ```

  Because Vim already does that as part of its `filetype` mechanism that you turn "on" three times in your `.vimrc`.
- And this one:

  ```
  " Execute the syntax autocommands for the each buffer.
  doautoall filetype BufRead
  ```

  Because your `.vimrc` is sourced *before* any buffer is loaded. That command will be executed on the first file you edit and never again in the current session.
- And this one:

  ```
  highlight Visual term=reverse  cterm=reverse  gui=reverse  guifg=Grey50
  ```

  Because setting terminal highlight attributes in a code block that is only executed within GVim makes no sense.
- And let's not talk about the mixed tabs and spaces, the trailing spaces and the meaningless comments:

  ```
  " For sure anyting under .vim/ gets executed automaticall. I've checked.
  ```

`:help new-filetype` tells you how to add support for a custom filetype. You should read it carefully (I suggest method `C`).

Comment: When I read the first sentence of your (long and correct) answer, I _knew_ it was you :-) Nobody else writes such helpful rants!

Comment: @IngoKarkat, thanks, I guess that's my trademark. Your rants are less "rant-y" but super helpful too!

Comment: @romainl thank you for your inputs. I will clear up the mess. I am still not sure though, that what's the reason for the colorscheme to not load onto a file opened used :tabnew from inside one file. The first file opened from the terminal loads the colorscheme just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at what Amal Khailtash is doing in his SystemVerilog/OVM syntax files:

[vim-syntax-highlighting-systemverilog-and-ovm](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/downloads/vim-syntax-highlighting-systemverilog-and-ovm)

I've been using his files for the past several years and have no problems with the highlighting of systemverilog files in multiple tabs and split windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the following command @Ady
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sv set filetype=verilog

I used 
au BufRead,BufNewFile * set filetype=verilog
to set all files in tabnew to verilog format. Atleast this way the files have some color and I can keep adding different filetype settings for different extensions as I move forward

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to vote up questions and answers that you found helpful.